# How to use WiFi connection on Nexus 4?

Tags: wireless, ubuntu-touch, nexus-4

I installed Ubuntu on my Nexus 4 for development , and after the installation, I wanted to connect it to my WiFi network. But, I can't add WiFi settings because I can only check the box "Auto-join previous networks".

So, either I misunderstand how the WiFi settings work, or I have a real problem with my WiFi settings.

Answer (score 1):

I had some problem because my nexus had installed Android 4.4 (Kit-Kat) and the radio firmware not is compatible with Ubuntu. You need flash radio on Nexus with version Android 4.3 or lower

```
fastboot flash radio radio_android_4.3.img
```